# Kvm host not reachable even though guests are

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, ping

I've got a debian server running multiple virtual machines (all debian-based as well) using KVM.

Everything went well but some time ago, the host decided to not respond to ping echo requests anymore. Also the ssh server seems to not be reachable. I.e. all communication to the server does not work. However: the KVM guests are still reachable and are working properly. The server also has an outgoing connection (pinging other hosts, internal to the network or external, works). I had a look in my main firewall and there the server displayed as being normally online. As that all sounded like a dns issue, I also checked using the IP (v4 and v6) address. Nothing. To make sure, I also checked using another machine and also one of the guest VMs did not get a ping reply.

After some months, it was somehow fixed and I could connect again but since I last rebooted the server, the host seems to be offline again.

Does anybody know what that could be? Is there any way a host could have anything blocked, even the ICMP echo requests, automatically, still allowing all the connections to the guests?

Comment: After the reboot your firewall went back to the previous configuration. However by default the firewall accepts everything, is it possible you misconfigured it? Can you get access to the server's console and check `iptables -nvL`?

Comment: Unfortunately, my internal firewall does not contain any rules and the policy is ACCEPT an thus, nothing should be blocked.